# Can the optical image stabilization be turned off on iPhone 6s Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I'm developing an app for some research purpose on iPhone 6s Plus, which equipped with optical image stabilization (OIS).

I was wondering is it possible to disable OIS, not digital image stabilization, on iPhone 6s Plus?

Comment: Well have you looked at the API documentation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe did you in the mean time and found something?

Comment: @meaning-matters I wasn't offering! And even if I had it may well have changed in the five years since I wrote that.